# Python - get unique and sorted values in list of lists

Tags: python, list

I want to manipulate the result to get from this :

```
[[50, 100],[100, 130],[20, 50, 100, 130]]
```

to this :

```
[[0, 50, 100, 0],[0 ,0, 100, 130],[20, 50, 100, 130]]
```

The idea is to fill gaps between same values ​​with zeros, which would indicate the absence of value until the same value is reached.

Comment: Is there any rule hehind, I saw the rule for 1st and 2nd list is different.

Comment: Would you elaborate more on your expectations?

Comment: What's the logic behind your question?

Comment: So `[20,50]` should become `[20,50,0,0]`? What about `[20,100]` or even  `[130,20]`?

Comment: How do you define a gap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question does not clearly state that: This anwer **assumes** that the entries in all list *should* be sorted afterwards and that each number is unique within each sublist.

You can reach this as follows:

```
numbers = [[50, 100],[100, 130],[20, 50, 100, 130]]

unique = sorted({n for l in numbers for n in l})

new_numbers = [[x if x in l else 0 for x in unique] for l in numbers]

new_numbers
> [[0, 50, 100, 0], [0, 0, 100, 130], [20, 50, 100, 130]]
```

Some explanation on the solution: First, get all (unique) numbers that occur in the original list. Then, go through the original list and add 0 to places, where a number from the unique numbers is not part of the sublist. Note that during this operation, the original list will be sorted, so `[100, 50]` will become `[0, 50, 100, 0]`.

edit: made more pythonic due to juanpa.arrivillaga's comment.

Comment: Can you explain the logic?

Comment: @PeterWood I added an explanation. Is this sufficient?

Comment: thanks, it works as expected

Comment: Keep in mind that this answer is based on the assumption that the sub-lists are always pre-sorted numerically. Your question indicates that the only requirement is for the shorter sub-lists to be filled with zeroes until the same values with the longest sub-list are reached, in which case the said assumption is not necessarily valid and you should take a look at my answer, which preserves the original order of the longest sub-list.

Comment: @blhsing There is no requirement that the sublists _are_ ordered, but indeed they _become_ ordered.

Comment: @Markus: requirement guessing is always risky; I noted, that all given lists are ordered and the question des not state otherwise.

Comment: There is not need to call `list` on a `set` just to pass to `sorted`, which accepts any iterable, (it will be converted to a list internally anyway).  You could just use a set-comprehension as well. `{n for l in numbers for n in l}`

Answer (score -1):

You first find the list of all unique possible numbers and store it in a sorted list `s`. Then you navigate through all sublists in the original list and then for sublist, navigate through the sorted list and return the element if it is in the sorted list, if not a 0

```
>>> l = [[50, 100],[100, 130],[20, 50, 100, 130]]
>>> s = sorted(set([e for sl in l for e in sl]))
>>> [[e if e in sl else 0 for e in s] for sl in l]
[[0, 50, 100, 0], [0, 0, 100, 130], [20, 50, 100, 130]]
```

Comment: Please explain the logic of this question

Comment: @U9-Forward. Added some explanation

Answer (score -1):

```
l = [[50, 100],[100, 130],[20, 50, 100, 130]]
r = sorted(l, key=len)[-1]
print([[n if n in i else 0 for n in r] for i in l])
```

This outputs:

```
[[0, 50, 100, 0], [0, 0, 100, 130], [20, 50, 100, 130]]
```